# Blur text in TextView unexpected behaviour

Tags: android

I'm trying to blur text in a TextView using setMaskFilter, the behavior seems unexpected, upper case chars, and new line, are not getting blurred, what's wrong with the below?

```
                textView.setText(feed.getText());
                BlurMaskFilter.Blur style = BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL ;

                float radius = textView.getTextSize() ;
                BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, style);
                textView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
                //The text is blurred here but Bes are not 
                textView.setText("Blah blah Blah blah");
                //This is blurred completely 
                textView.setText("blah blah blah blah");
```

Answer (score 3):

Go through the tutorial , you can find the solution

http://android--examples.blogspot.in/2015/11/how-to-use-blurmaskfilter-in-android.html